# Does this series converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is this series convergent or divergent?

$$\sum ((2n+1)e^{-1/n}-(2n-1)) $$

I tried to apply the comparison test, but I did not get very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track. If you Taylor expand the term $e^{-\frac{1}{n}}$, then you can see that

$$1-\dfrac{1}{n}+ \dfrac{1}{2n^2} - \dfrac{1}{6n^3} \leq e^{-\frac{1}{n}} \leq 1-\dfrac{1}{n}+ \dfrac{1}{2n^2}$$, and then apply the Comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

The taylor expansion $$e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\dots$$is helpful.

Modulo a convergent series, the original series is comparable with the harmonic series $\sum 1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to the already accepted answer. Since
$$ e^{-1/n}=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{m! n^m} \tag{1}$$
we have:
$$ (2n+1)e^{-1/n}-(2n-1) = \sum_{m\geq 2}\frac{(-1)^m}{(m+1)m\cdot(m-2)!}\cdot\frac{1}{n^m}\tag{2}$$
and
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left[(2n+1)e^{-1/n}-(2n-1)\right]=\color{red}{\sum_{m\geq 2}\frac{(-1)^m \zeta(m)}{(m+1)m\cdot(m-2)!}}\tag{3}$$
where the RHS is a fast-converging series with alternating signs.
The Laplace transform gives that the RHS of $(3)$ also equals:
$$ 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{J_3(2x)}{e^{x^2}-1}\,dx \tag{4}$$
where $J_3$ is a [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).